# select and delete attributes with JQ

Tags: json, jq

## Info

I have a terraform state file (json) with some deprecated attributes.

I would like to remove theses deprecated attributes.

I try to use `jq` and `select()` && `del()` but did not succeed to get back my full json without the deprecated attribue timeouts.

## Problem

How to get my full json without the attribute `timeouts` for only one type of resources `google_dns_record_set`.

## Data

```json
{
  "version": 4,
  "terraform_version": "1.0.6",
  "serial": 635,
  "lineage": "6a9c2392-fdae-2b54-adcc-7366f262ffa4",
  "outputs": {"test":"test1"},
  "resources": [
  {
      "module": "module.resources",
      "mode": "data",
      "type": "google_client_config"
  },
  {
      "module": "module.xxx.module.module1[\"cluster\"]",
      "mode": "managed",
      "type": "google_dns_record_set",
      "name": "public_ip_ic_dns",
      "provider": "module.xxx.provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google\"]",
      "instances": [
        {
          "schema_version": 0,
          "attributes": {
            "id": "projects/xxx-xxx/managedZones/xxx--public/rrsets/*.net1.cluster.xxx--public.net.com./A",
            "managed_zone": "xxx--public",
            "name": "*.net1.cluster.xxx--public.net.com.",
            "project": "xxx-xxx",
            "rrdatas": [
              "11.22.33.44"
            ],
            "timeouts": null,
            "ttl": 300,
            "type": "A"
          },
          "sensitive_attributes": [],
          "private": "xxx",
          "dependencies": [
            "xxx"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

## Command

```sh
jq -r '.resources[] | select(.type=="google_dns_record_set").instances[].attributes | del(.timeouts)' data.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull the `del` command up front to include the whole selection as its own filter

```sh
del(.resources[] | select(.type=="google_dns_record_set").instances[].attributes.timeouts)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/FIdvIf115i)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was so quick i can't accept your answer for now, but i will in 2 minutes